# how to insert keyframe for pose

Tags: animation, keyframes

I need to insert keyframe for the pose I have made in posemode. How can I do that? when I hit i it writes some error (keying set failed to set any keyframes or something like that)

Comment: Does this help? http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16531/keying-set-failed-to-insert-any-keyframes

Comment: nope, I just don't know, how you can insert keyframe for singular bones, I think, that if it was this I wouldn't be able to set keyframe to anything

Comment: so key-framing  is working for other objects but not the bones ?

Comment: it most probably is working for them too, but I don't know, how to do it. (if I just need to hit i when the bones are selected, then itš just as you said)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to select what type of keyframe you want to add? It is at the bottom just after the type of sync that you would like to keep while playing your animation.
Or if you would not want to set a specific type of keyframe, please click on the red button on the left of type of keyframe.