# Keyframing problem

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm pretty new to Blender and a few days ago I started working on my first animation. Everything went well until suddenly I couldn't add any new keyframes to the majority of my objects. The error message "Keying set failed to insert any keyframes" keeps popping up and I have no idea how to fix it. I've added a link to a .blend file down below with just the camera and some other objects in it. the camera is one of  many objects Blender won't let me animate.

I'd be really greatful if someone could help me 'cause I've been working on this for a long time already.

Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please use exclusively [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) if you want to provide files for us to check. Random file sharing services won't keep them up long enough. [Further tips on how to improve your questions](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please)

Comment: Related (needs an update for 2.8): https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16531/keying-set-failed-to-insert-any-keyframes?r=SearchResults